# Catch Exceptions thrown during layout

Tags: flutter

Can you catch exceptions thrown in flutter during layout of the Widgets, like it is attempted in the example below that does not work?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _offendingTestBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _offendingTestBody() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: _columnOrListView(List.filled(22, Text("test")))),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _columnOrListView(List<Widget> children) {
    try {
      return Column(
        children: children,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return ListView(
        children: children,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The following message appears in the log, which seems to indicate that the rendering library - unneccessarily - catches the exception before my code can get to it.

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 74 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///Users/user/StudioProjects/cols_try_catch/lib/main.dart:39:14
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#74fc7 relayoutBoundary=up4 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=390.0, h=300.0)
...  size: Size(26.0, 300.0)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't catch layout errors like this, they are thrown in the layout phase long after your build method has returned.

Looking at the code I believe you want to pass `shrinkWrap: true` to the ListView, which will cause it to size itself to the height of the children (like a Column) but scroll if it exceeds the maximum height available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. shrinkWrap is not the solution to the original problem that the above code should solve if it were to work: The purpose was to remove the "scrollability" if there is enough space to have a non-scrollable Column. With the shrinkWrap:true in ListView you still get the blue strips at top and bottom on Android or the actual scroll movement on iOS when trying to scroll.

Comment: I believe SingleChildScrollView doesn't have an overscroll effect when shorter than the available height, you could wrap that around a Column

Comment: Indeed, that works. Thanks. A bit weird that this isn't standard behaviour for ListView as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to catch an error, maybe you should separate it from build process.., but sometime your process may return error you can use `FutureBuilder` to catch an error

Comment: There is no async code involved in what I am trying to do. How would the FutureBuilder be helpful?

Comment: Hello jakob, maybe you can wrap your code that will throw your error and use FutuBuilder to catch and display error message, you an check this link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of doc, thank you. ;) Take my code sample and demonstrate that your suggestion works. I tried and it did not.

Comment: `Widget _columnOrListViewFutureBuilder(List<Widget> children) {
    return FutureBuilder<Widget>(
        future: _columnForList(children),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
          } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            return snapshot.data!;
          }
          return ListView(
            children: children,
          );
        });
    return Container();
  }

  Future<Widget> _columnForList(List<Widget> children) async {
    return Column(
      children: children,
    );
  }` With the same message